# How can I prove that the NPN BJT is in the active region?

Tags: transistors

I created the following circuit using a npn transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKgcLh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After measuring all the voltages, I got: \$ V_{BE}\approx 0.6V, V_{CB}>0 \$. Are those measurements sufficient to say that the transistor is operating in the active region? How can I prove it theoretically?

Also, I'm looking for books/websites/documentation containing different transistor circuits and the explanation of their function. If someone could help me, I'd gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. Vbe must be forward biased as well.  The chart shows clear definition.

[image]

[More reading from Berkeley U.](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee130/sp03/lecture/lecture15.pdf)

Here is a simulation of Vce=0 forced by shorted Vce with only 0 to 200mV Vbe.
Note how collector current is much less than base current.  This demonstrates the non-linearity of saturation but is not a practical circuit.

[image]

Comment: yes but Vbe could be any value forward biased, so not explicit

Comment: +1 for nice graph showing the whole universe. I'd add to OP's list of requirements that *some* collector current should flow in active region.

Comment: In the real world, the presented circuit will never drive \$V_{CB}\$ to 0, and so it would never enter saturation according to this definition.

Comment: For hand calculation we might use this model, but OP asked about the case where he measured the voltages on an actual circuit.

Comment: For the circuit with Vcc = 0, how do propose to get the BJT into forward active mode to make the circuit useful as an amplifier?

Comment: Obviously the load line must change.. Increase Vce. One circuit cannot exercise all modes.

Answer (score 3):

> After measuring all the voltages, I got: \$ V_{BE}\approx 0.6V, V_{CB}>0 \$. Are those measurements sufficient to say that the transistor is operating in the active region?

No, it's not sufficient. You could measure the same two conditions if the BJT is in saturation.

If \$V_{CE} > ~0.2\ {\rm V}\$, then it's very likely the part is in forward active mode. If \$V_{CB} > 0\$, as you said in comments, then it's safe to say the device is in active mode.

But the definition of saturation is somewhat fuzzy, and might be defined differently by different manufacturers or for BJTs designed for different applications. Also, it's usually defined in terms of current, not voltage. A typical definition of saturation is when \$\beta < 10\$ (or 20, or some other value). So to prove the BJT is in forward-active, you'd need to work out the base and collector currents, and show their ratio is above the threshold you've chosen to define saturation.

Theoretically, there's nothing really to prove. You just have to make a clear definition of the boundary between active and saturated, and then see whether your operating point matches that definition or not.

**Note:** I made a mistake and gave the condition \$V_{CB} > 0.2\$ instead of \$V_{CE}>0.2\$ when I first wrote this, which might have led to much of the discussion in comments. Now corrected.

Comment: More Likely is not a clear definition

Comment: @Tony, which is why I went on to explain "the definition of saturation is somewhat fuzzy", and the implications of that.

Comment: @The_Photon. My definition is clear.  Degree of saturation is measured many ways including a log scale of asymmetric induced sine harmonic distortion due to parabolic curve, but usually Vce(sat) @ some I.

Comment: @Tony, Clear but useless, since Vce never goes to 0 in this circuit in the real world.

Comment: @ThePhoton .... r u sure about that.... what happens with Vcc = 0V

Comment: @Trevor, ok you got me. In the real world, under this definition, the transistor never becomes saturated in any useful implementation of the circuit.

Comment: If I understood correctly, there's no way to theoretically prove that this circuit is in active mode. However, I can assume that since \$ V_{CB}>0.2V \$ and \$ V_C>V_B>V_E \$ the transistor is in active mode and \$i_C=βI_B\$. Are the previous statements  correct?

Comment: "How can I prove it theoretically? "  By using my Saturation definition. Vbe>0 and Vbc>0 for NPN.  In practice I use Vce<2V at rated current asymmetry >~1% for sine input but depends on Vbe modulation range. Thats my Rule of Thumb.

Comment: @BillarasKal, yes, if you measured \$V_{BE} > 0.6\$ and \$V_{CB} > 0\$, then that's safely in saturation. Tony's definition is not a good one to use if you want to know if your c.e. amplifier circuit will be able to provide linear amplification.

Comment: @ThePhonon, I am just saying your statement "Vce never goes to 0 in this circuit in the real world" is false.  As for the rest of this argument.... With no R values.... it is impossible to tell what state the transistor is in.

Comment: @Trevor, you could measure \$V_{BE}\$ and \$V_{CB}\$ like  OP said s/he did.

Comment: If you get \$V_{CB}  < 0\$ but small in magnitude, then you have to be more careful as I outlined in my answer.

Comment: To add to what @The_Photon said about the definition being imprecise, the traditional definition of "saturation region" for a MOSFET is basically the _opposite_ of what it is for a BJT.  So just be very careful about using the phrase, and prefer to specify what is actually happening.

Comment: @ThePhoton, and with R1 = 0 and R2 large that's would be pretty saturated wouldn't it...

Comment: @Trevor, but we're talking about the situation where you don't know the R values. I proposed a way to test if the BJT is in saturation, which you said wasn't possible.

Comment: @The photon, original question was.... With this circuit and these measurements can you tell if it is operating in the active region? Answer - " NOT ENOUGH INFORMATION "

Comment: @Trevor, read the first sentence of my answer (after I quoted OP).

Comment: @ThePhoton Right... :) That's what I said too.. LOL (I didn't notice it was your own answer) My bad... appologies.

Comment: `No, it's not sufficient. You could measure the same two conditions if the BJT is in saturation.`
How can a NPN transistor in saturation if VCB > 0?